# ¿Se puede hacer pasar el contenido de un String por el nombre de una variable?

Tags: java

Entenderán en seguida la pregunta con el siguiente código:

```
public static void setNewValue(String field, int newValue) {
    for (Position specificPosition : positionsData) {
        specificPosition.field = newValue;
    }
}
```

Tengo el siguiente método y me gustaría saber si existe alguna manera de que el atributo del objeto `specificPosition` quede determinado por el contenido del parámetro `field` de forma que, por ejemplo, si `field == "latitud"` entonces el `for` sería.

```
for (Position specificPosition : positionsData) {
    specificPosition.latitud = newValue;
}
```

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Necesitas usar la [reflexión](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javareflection.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

entiendo lo que necesitas, pero no vas a poder, en principio sólo puedes acceder a atributos de un objeto y no puedes hacer una especie de casteo para saber el atributo al que pretendes accedes.

Lo que si puedes hacer es un swich y en base a la variable que necesites del objeto, acceder a ella directamente, por ejemplo:

```
public static void setNewValue(String field, int newValue) {
    swich (field) {
        case "latitud":
            for (Position specificPosition : positionsData)
                specificPosition.latitud = newValue;
            break;
        case "longitud":
            for (Position specificPosition : positionsData)
                specificPosition.longitud = newValue;
            break;
    }
}
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Comment: Ya me imaginaba que no se podía. En condiciones normales recurriría al switch o incluso a un conjunto de ifs. Pero por diversas circunstancias no puedo recurrir a ellos y esta era una idea que habia tenido para poder hacer test unitarios. En fin, historia muy larga jeje. Gracias por tu aportación ;)